# Why does traitCollectionDidChange() execute twice on suspending application

Tags: ios, swift

I override `traitCollectionDidChange` on a view controller and have noticed that it's been called twice on suspending the application.

In addition, a check if the trait collection has a different color appearance returns:

- the first time execution - the opposite `userInterfaceStyle`
- the second time execution - the original `userInterfaceStyle`.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
            print(traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle.rawValue);
        }
    }
}
```